# Envio de email con cron y con acentos

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

Quiero enviar un mail mediante un cron, el mail es de testeo para ver qué es lo que falla con otros crones que tengo. Estoy enviando concretamente esto:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /root/tareas/scripts/test/header.txt /root/tareas/scripts/test/facturas_a_gestionar.txt /root/tareas/scripts/test/footer.txt > /root/tareas/scripts/test/cuerpo.html;


DESTINATARIO="mimail@gmail.com";

ASUNTO="áéíóú ñ Ñ Facturas para gestionar";

mail -s "$(echo -e "$ASUNTO \nContent-Type: text/html")"  $DESTINATARIO  < /root/tareas/scripts/test/cuerpo.html
```

Si lo envío manualmente, es decir, parándome en la carpeta /root/tareas/scripts/test/ y ejecutando el comando `./test.sh` el mail llega perfecto, con acentos y ñ, pero si lo armo para automatizarlo no me toma las Ñ ni los acentos.

Estaba pensando que tal vez no tiene la ubicación real de algo y por eso no puede ejecutarlo, por eso le puse rutas definidas a todo, pero no sé qué más podría hacer... ¿se puede poner una ruta al comando **mail**?

Comment: Tal vez requieras verificar la codificacion "text/html charset=UTF-8" Mira este post https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/the_importance_of_content-type_character_encoding_in_html_emails/

Comment: Hola @RubenHernandez! Estuve mirando el link, pero en ese caso pone datos en el  email header pero no se donde es eso..vos tenes idea? GraciaS!!

Comment: Si aca mira "$ASUNTO \nContent-Type: text/html")"

Comment: @RubenHernandez ¡buena sugerencia! Juan Manuel, ¿te funcionó?

Comment: Hola @RubenHernandez no, no me funciono, lo tengo asi: /bin/mail -s "$(echo -e "$ASUNTO \nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")"  $MAILAGENTE  < cuerpo.html   Donde MAILAGENTE es el mail de la persona, y /bin/mail es la ubicacion esacta del comando mail para que el cron lo tome correctamente